# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare WP_Post_Type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou com um problema no Wordpress de um cliente, não consigo consertar. Está apresentando o seguinte erro.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare WP_Post_Type::$show_in_rest in
>   /home/thesearchhouseco/public_html/buzios/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php
>   on line 348

Já apaguei as linhas conforme mencionado, porém, ele continua apresentando erro em outra página.

É possível visualizar o erro no endereço:
https://thesearchhouse.com.br/buzios/

Comment: Você apagou a linha 348 de class-wp-post-type.php?

Comment: Sim, não, ele dá erro em outro linha depois disso.